# Java Date and Time remove time zone from given date " 2019-12-03T10:00:00-06:00 " and expected date is "2019-12-03T10:00:00"

Tags: java, java-8

```
LocalDateTime formatOrderEndDateTime;
    try {
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME;
        formatOrderEndDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse("2019-12-03T10:00:01+01:00", formatter);
        System.out.println(formatOrderEndDateTime);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
```

Above code is working as expected but its not working if time zone is not available .

given input date :  2019-12-03T10:00:00-06:00 or 2019-12-03T10:00:00

expected o/p date:  2019-12-03T10:00:00

my code should work for both with time zone and without time zone input dates

Comment: If `ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME` fails (i.e. `DateTimeParseException`) try `ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME`. If that fails as well, handle the exception

Comment: expecting out put  2019-12-03T10:00:00   for both 2019-12-03T10:00:00-06:00 or 2019-12-03T10:00:00

Comment: "my code should work for both with time zone and without time zone input dates"? So you want to **ignore** anything that indicates a time zone offset? That means you actively want to parse dates wrong, do you understand that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you will have to use a different pair of formatters as shown in the code below. From the documentation of `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME`:

> The ISO-like date-time formatter that formats or parses a date-time withthe offset and zone if available, such as '2011-12-03T10:15:30','2011-12-03T10:15:30+01:00' or '2011-12-03T10:15:30+01:00[Europe/Paris]'.

Then you will have to use a different formatter to convert it into string instead of using `LocalDateTime.toString()`.

```
LocalDateTime formatOrderEndDateTime;
try {
     DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME;
     formatOrderEndDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(line.trim(), formatter);

     DateTimeFormatter f2 = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME;
     System.out.println(formatOrderEndDateTime.format( f2 ));
} catch (Exception e) {
     System.err.println( e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage() );
}
```

So, this allows providing input in any of the multiple supported formats and then creating a string in the format we want.

Answer (score 4):

## Moment

> given input date : 2019-12-03T10:00:00-06:00 or 2019-12-03T10:00:00

Those are two very different animals.

The first represents a moment, a specific point on the timeline. The second does not. Is the second one 10 AM in Tokyo, 10 AM in Toulouse, or 10 AM in Toledo — three very different moments several hours apart.

The first should be parsed as a `OffsetDateTime`. The second should be parsed as a `LocalDateTime`.

## Wrong type

For an input such as `2019-12-03T10:00:00-06:00`, parse as an `OffsetDateTime`. You used the `LocalDateTime` which cannot handle the offset from UTC at the end of that string.

No need to specify a formatting pattern. Your input complies with ISO 8601 standard, used by default.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse( "2019-12-03T10:00:00-06:00" )
```

## Wrong formatter

To generate text in ISO 8601 format that omits the offset, use [`DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME).

```
String output = odt.format( DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME ) ;
```

## Offset versus time zone

> not working if time zone

Your inputs do not have a time zone. They have an offset-from-UTC. An offset is merely a number of hours-minutes-seconds.

A time zone is much more. A time zone is a history of past, present, and future changes to the offset used by the people of a particular region. A time zone has a name in `Continent/Region` form such as `Europe/Paris`.

Comment: `2019-12-03T10:00:00`, `The second does not. Is the second one 10 AM in Tokyo, 10 AM in Toulouse, or 10 AM in Toledo`. Isn't that format default to UTC?

Answer (score 1):

### You shouldn’t want a LocalDateTime

As an example: The two strings `2019-12-03T10:00:01+09:00` and `2019-12-03T10:00:01-08:00` denote points in time 17 hours apart, yet will be parsed into equal `LocalDateTime` objects. I don’t think you want that.

Also `LocalDateTime` is probably unsuited for an order end time. It’s doesn’t know any time zone or offset from UTC, so every person and every piece of code seeing it will be free to interpret into the time zone they happen to think of and not the intended one. This leaves a great risk of unintended results. For at least 19 out of 20 purposes you will be better off with an `Instant`, an `OffsetDateTime` or a `ZonedDateTime`.

### Parsing with and without offset: define a default time zone

You need to accept strings that come without an offset. Then you also need to know which time zone to assume for such strings — a default time zone. Then you can parse them too.

For example:

```
    ZoneId defaultTimeZone = ZoneId.of("America/Guatemala");
    ZoneId resultTimeZone = ZoneId.of("Europe/Rome");
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME)
            .appendPattern("[XXX]")
            .toFormatter();


    for (String input : new String[] {
            "2019-12-03T10:00:01+01:00",
            "2019-12-03T10:00:00-06:00",
            "2019-12-03T10:00:00"
    }) {
        TemporalAccessor parsed = formatter.parseBest(input,
                OffsetDateTime::from, LocalDateTime::from);
        ZonedDateTime dateTime;
        if (parsed instanceof OffsetDateTime) {
            dateTime = ((OffsetDateTime) parsed).atZoneSameInstant(resultTimeZone);
        } else {
            dateTime = ((LocalDateTime) parsed).atZone(defaultTimeZone)
                    .withZoneSameInstant(resultTimeZone);
        }
        System.out.format("%-25s is parsed into %s%n", input, dateTime);
    }
```

Output from this snippet is:

> ```
> 2019-12-03T10:00:01+01:00 is parsed into 2019-12-03T10:00:01+01:00[Europe/Rome]
> 2019-12-03T10:00:00-06:00 is parsed into 2019-12-03T17:00+01:00[Europe/Rome]
> 2019-12-03T10:00:00       is parsed into 2019-12-03T17:00+01:00[Europe/Rome]
> ```

I am using `[XXX]` in the format pattern string to denote an optional offset. The call to `parseBest()` parses into an `OffsetDateTime` if it can (the offset is present), otherwise into a `LocalDateTime` that I subsequently convert. Finally I convert all parsed dates and times into one time zone so the user can see consistent results.